# C# Extending the Authenticate Attribute (ASP.NET Core 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to add a flag into the request `HttpContext.Items.Add("Flag","FlagValue")` after the user authenticates. I have done similar tasks like this using a separate `ActionFilterAttribute` but wanted to do in by extending or overriding the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

I know this can be done using by creating a custom authorize attribute and I've looked at a lot of examples online but the sample I've found doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

I started something simple to see if it authenticates

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    public AuthorizeUserAttribute() 
    {
        Log.Information("Authenticated?"); // stops here
    }

    public AuthorizeUserAttribute(string policy) : base(policy) 
    {
        Log.Information("Authenticated?"); // doesn't stop here
    }
}
```

and is getting authenticated and checking on the Policies I've created.

```
[CheckIsAppLocked]
[HttpGet("connections")]
[AuthorizeUser(Policy = "App_User")]
public ActionResult<Packet<List<SFTP_Conn_Info>>> GetConnInfo() 
{
    return OK(HomeLogic.GetConnInfo());
}
```

My problem is that I cannot tap into the `HttpContext` class. I don't know the methods I can expose with `AuthorizeAttribute`, I even tried using the `HttpContextAccessor` class but it returns null (but when used with the an action filter is not null)

I can call in the action filter `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)` and reference the actionContext.HttpContext class.

my guess there is a method I need to define in my AuthorizeAttribute but not sure which one is supported in .NET 6.

Help appreciated!

Comment: why are you extending that - you should just be configuring via policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IActionFilter {
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {}
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext) {
        actionContext.HttpContext.Items.Add("Flag", GetFlagValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the `IActionFilter` interface on your defined attribute, you should be able to access the `HttpContext` as you've mentioned from the declared attribute on your actions.

Comment: That did the trick! I didn't know I was able implement ActionFilter in the AuthorizeAttribute. here is my fill code if someone needs this